# Jenkins > Blue Ocean > Build from latest commit

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-blueocean

To clarify, what I'm looking for is a `Build from latest commit` rather than `Build from current commit`.

I don't see a Build (from latest commit) button in Blue Ocean. I've got to be missing something, right?!

In Classic View you have "Schedule a Scan for pipeline" so, if you've just pushed something to git you can Rebuild.

However, in Blue Ocean you just have the Replay button (which just runs the last commit it has already pulled down).

How do you force Blue Ocean to pull the latest commit?!

Answer (score 1):

Currently, there is no rebuild option in blueocean [see here](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-49348?attachmentViewMode=list)

Answer (score 0):

When you view the last build for a certain branch, there is a "reload" style button on the upper right side. This allows you to run a build again:

[image]

In the *Activity* screen, the same button is also visible:

[image]

Comment: @Snowcrash did this answer your question? If yes, please mark it as solved. Thanks.

Comment: This is replay which is different than rebuild and very confusing. It will fail if pipelines are using dynamic nodes.